# How get in azure dev ops id of two last git commits?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to get 2 last id commits of Git repo last one I got using $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE) but I need to get one commit id before generated from $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)

is this possible ??

Comment: If you can run a git command in the repository cloned, you could try `git rev-parse $(Build.SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE)~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to need to use the REST API.

Since you already have the first commit needed, you might find simple success with [Get Commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) using the `searchCriteria.$top` and `searchCriteria.fromCommitId`.